# php ajax jquery - on submit only works once

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a form that submits shopping cart information to a handler file, which works perfectly. I'm now trying to incorporate ajax and jquery to give a better user experience.

My problem is that the code only works on the first submit.

Here's my js code:

```
$(function(){
    $('form.addtoCart').on('submit', function() {
        var that = $(this),
            url = '/ajax/handlerCart.php',
            type = that.attr('method'),
            data = {};

        that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value) {
            var that = $(this),
                name = that.attr('name'),
                value = that.val();

            data[name] = value; 
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: type,
            data: data,
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                $('#nav_cart').load('/ajax/nav_cart.php');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Here is my html:

```
<form action="" method="post" class="addtoCart">
    <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="Price" value="5">
    <input type="submit" value="Add" name="Add">
</form>
```

Things I've done:

1) I've tried looking at the Chrome Console, and it looks like the script is working after each click. The first response says "worked" and I click a subsequent 7 times as you can see in the image below.

[chrome console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEfPk.jpg)

2) I don't think this is an Event Delegation problem because there are no new descendants being added to my html.

3) I thought that there might be a problem load() only working once, so I've also tried removing the following line of code:

```
$('#nav_cart').load('/ajax/nav_cart.php');
```

The problem still persists.

4) I've tried having the handler return echo time(). I thought maybe the browser was blocking repeated javascript responses and that didn't work.

I've tried my best to research this problem, but I can't find the solution or I just don't understand the solutions people are providing to others. I apologize in advance, I'm still quite new to jquery/ajax.

Thanks for your time.

Edit:

My form is located in index.php. nav_cart.php is loaded into a div#nav_cart (also in index.php) once the ajax has been successful. Sorry if this was unclear.

Comment: where did you put the jquery code?

Comment: before the end of the html body, i reference the file that my jquery code is in. <script src="/functions/scripts.js"></script>

Comment: Check the network tab and see what data gets sent on second submit.

Comment: Try with placing this code within `nav_cart.php` too

Comment: @ReneKorss on subsequent submits, I see handlerCart.php post, nav_cart get...I think. I believe that's what I should be expecting.

Comment: Show us your `nav_cart.php`. jQuery code is working, as you can see from console. Just the response is changing. So some sent data must be changing or something like that.

Comment: @ReneKorss You are absolutely right. Wow. Thank you so much for helping me figure out there was nothing wrong with the jquery!! It was actually my handler that was creating the problem when all this time I thought it was jquery/ajax. The problem was that subsequent submits weren't being proceed by my handler.

Comment: @ReneKorss what do i do now that the question has been solved? how do i close it and give you credit?

Comment: I added little answer to explain what was wrong. You can now accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery code is working, as you can see from console. It registeres response. Only that response is empty. Problem must lie in your `/ajax/handlerCart.php` and how it responds to request.

Comment: I am marking this as correct, but the problem was with the handler handlerCart.php not with the response file nav_cart.php.

Comment: Sorry. Fixed it. I meant `/ajax/handlerCart.php` since this gives the response, not `nav_cart.php`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding preventDefault() method to prevent the default submision?

```
 $(function(){
    $('form.addtoCart').on('submit', function(e) { //addede e here to get the event object
        e.preventDefault(); // preventing the default submit
        var that = $(this),
            url = '/ajax/handlerCart.php',
            type = that.attr('method'),
            data = {};

        that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value) {
            var that = $(this),
                name = that.attr('name'),
                value = that.val();

            data[name] = value; 
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: type,
            data: data,
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                $('#nav_cart').load('/ajax/nav_cart.php');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry I should've mentioned that. Yes, I have.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $('form.addtoCart').on('submit', function() {
        var that = $(this),
            url = '/ajax/handlerCart.php',
            type = that.attr('method'),
            data = {};

        that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value) {
            var that = $(this),
                name = that.attr('name'),
                value = that.val();

            data[name] = value; 
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: type,
            data: data,
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                $('#nav_cart').load('/ajax/nav_cart.php');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Add this on /ajax/nav_cart.php instead of referencing it on the HTML

Comment: nav_cart.php is a separate functionality that just displays the results of the updated cart once the form is submitted and everything worked. so if I submit my form, nav_cart.php might show the total number of items in the cart. i'm not sure how putting the jquery in this nav_cart.php would solve the problem.

Comment: have you tried it? the form.addtoCart is in nav_cart.php?

Comment: the jquery code **must be loaded** with the nav cart evertime

Comment: @brian8 is using AJAX. So page is not reloaded. `nav_cart.php` gives just a response. Putting JS there is completely unneccessary.

Comment: @ReneKorss, exactly. its not reloaded, so the DOM element that is the initial target of jquery(_$('form.addtoCart')_) referenced in the HTML page, will be replaced by the **NEW** DOM after `$('#nav_cart').load('/ajax/nav_cart.php');`

Comment: Why do you think that this `form` is in `#nav_cart`? @brian8 is it?

Comment: @ramobrero I tried copying and pasting the jquery into nav_cart.php and unfortunately, it did not solve the problem.

Comment: @ReneKorss The form is not in nav_cart. The form is in, for example, index.php. #nav_cart is a div that is also in index.php. nav_cart.php is just a response that loads a result into #nav_cart if the ajax has been successful.

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to implement event delegation with jQuery. Because when you have loaded your page, DOM is created and event is assigned to your form.

But after you have made ajax request, you are replacing HTML based on your AJAX response. You are replacing your form element as well.

Though it is the same markup, but from DOM's point of view its a new element and event was assigned to old element with same markup.

You should bind event to some parent element which is not being replaced by your AJAX call, like below:

```
$('#parent_element').on('submit', '.addtoCart', function(event){
  // Your code here
});
```

More info: http://www.xpertdeveloper.com/2011/12/event-delegation-in-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

Don't use submit and form , you can replace it directly in html by a simple button :

```
<input type="button" value="Add" name="Add" class="mybutton">
```

And then use ajax :

```
 $(".mybutton").on("click",function(){

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: type,
        data: data,
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            $('#nav_cart').load('/ajax/nav_cart.php');
        }
    });


  })
```